# Looking for the name of a book from my childhood, that contains multiple stories

Tags: identification-request

I'm looking for the name of a children's book. Me and my sister were given it back in about 1993 by a relative who passed away too long ago so we have no way of asking them, and we ended up losing it in a house fire. We live in the UK. It was a book that contained several stories in a month, that continued throughout the rest of the year. For example, a story began on 1st January for a couple of pages, then we had to wait until the following month before we could read the next part of the story. The main problem we have, is that the only story we vaguely remember is one about a cupboard. The story starts off describing the cupboard and then the information increases in the following month. I know it sounds strange and extremely vague but it's been bugging me for about 20 years now.

Comment: Can you explain more about the format? Why did you *have* to wait, or was it on trust, like an advent calendar?

Comment: Was it a bound volume of a monthy magazine?